# bootstrap modal is not opening in Safari

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, jquery-steps

I want to open bootstrap modal on button click. It opens fine in windows browsers (IE, Edge, Chrome, FireBox), but it doesn't open in iOS-Safari browser. I see many developers having same issue but I didn't get any definitive solution so far.

Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loaderModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loaderModalTitle">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="position: absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="loaderDiv" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-5">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                            <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="font-size:60px; color:#0095fe;"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center" id="divSpinnertext"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var form = $("#createCustomerForm").steps({
    labels: {
      cancel: "CANCEL",
      finish: "FINISH",
      next: "NEXT",
      previous: "PREVIOUS"
    },

    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
        $("#loaderModal").modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: The following example works on iOS Safari:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#vertically-centered

Comment: I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/21849/) using your HTML code that calls your jQuery code on button click and it also works on iOS Safari.

Comment: Appreciate your responses. I works on button click for me also, but I am opening modal on click of a link (anchor tag <a href="#finish" role="menuitem">FINISH</a> )

Comment: And it just not work for Safari browser on iOS device

Comment: Could you update your question with the `<a>` link code?

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/22405/) also works on iOS Safari

Comment: I updated jQuery code. I am using a jQuery plugin : steps.js (jquery-steps.com). <a> link is generated by this plugin.

Comment: That makes a difference... Can you update the jsfiddle with a `jquery.steps` example that tries to accomplish the same task?